# how to scrape multiple values for a single cell

Tags: python, list, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the cast name from [rottentomatoes](https://editorial.rottentomatoes.com/guide/best-sci-fi-movies-of-all-time/). The first movie `THE HITCHHIKER'S GUIDE TO THE GALAXY` has four names as starring. They are  `Sam Rockwell, Zooey Deschanel, Yasiin Bey, Martin Freeman`. My code is totally fine with star **scraping**. However, instead seeing the name of the four actors for one movie, it shows the name of the four actors for four movies.

My code:

```
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate", "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "DNT":"1","Connection":"close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1"}
url= 'https://editorial.rottentomatoes.com/guide/best-sci-fi-movies-of-all-time/'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)#, proxies=proxies)
content = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
name =[]
year = []
rating = []
director = []
starring = []

movies = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'article_movie_title'})
for movie in movies:
  title = movie.find('h2').find('a').text
  name.append(title)
  release = movie.find('h2').find('span', attrs={'class':'subtle start-year'}).text
  year.append(release)
  R = movie.find('h2').find('span', attrs={'class':'tMeterScore'}).text
  rating.append(R)
  for d in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'info director'}):
    for a in d.find_all('a'):
      director.append(a.string)
  for c in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'info cast'}):
    for c1 in c.find_all('a'):
      starring.append(c1.text)
```

I create a dictionary and then create a csv table from that dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = {'Movie_name': name,
           'Release_year': year,
           'Movie_rating': rating,
           'Director of movie': director,
           'Starring': starring }
movie_All = pd.DataFrame({ key:pd.Series(value) for key, value in my_dict.items() })
movie_All.to_csv('movies_rot.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
movie_All.head()
```

The table looks like

[image]

It should looks like

```
         Movie_name                       Release_year  Movie_rating    Director of movie   Starring
0   The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy    (2005)    60%          Garth Jennings   Sam Rockwell,Zooey Deschanel,Yasiin Bey, Martin Freeman
```

How could I select the name of the star as per movies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to loop through the container or div class `row countdown-item` not the titles

```
movies = soup.select('.row.countdown-item')
for movie in movies:
  title = movie.select_one('h2 a').text
  name.append(title)
  release = movie.select_one('h2 .subtle').text
  year.append(release)
  R = movie.select_one('h2 .tMeterScore').text
  rating.append(R)
  # separate director name by comma
  D =  ', '.join([d.text for d in movie.select('.director a')])
  director.append(D)
  C =  ', '.join([c.text for c in movie.select('.cast a')])
  starring.append(C)
```

Comment: This code give same output for director and Starring. For example `The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (2005) 60%   Garth Jennings Garth Jennings`

Comment: solved? please mark the answer as accepted if it solved.

Comment: No it was not solved. `The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (2005) 60% Garth Jennings Garth Jennings
 The Endless (2018) 92% Justin Benson, Aaron Moorhead Justin Benson, Aaron Moorhead
 Los Cronocrímenes (Timecrimes) (2007) 89% Nacho Vigalondo Nacho Vigalondo
 Ad Astra (2019) 83% James Gray James Gray
 Westworld (1973) 86% Michael Crichton Michael Crichton` As you can see starring name and directors name are same for each movie which is a wrong output.

Comment: my bad, it should be `starring.append(C)`  not `D`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you only have a single dimension array for starring, and so when multiple values are added for one movie and the assumption is later made that each movie only has one actor, the program thinks that it is meant to be for the next movie. What you should do is create a string inside of the loop and then append the actor names and a comma to that string, like so:

```
starringForThisMovie = ""
for c in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'info cast'}):
   for c1 in c.find_all('a'):
      starringForThisMovie += c1.text + ", "
starring.append(starringForThisMovie)
```

Sorry for the bad explanation of why the issue is happening. I can't think of a better one at the moment.

Comment: It does not work. All the name of the star is shown for one movie. Suppose if there is four movie, 1st movie has 2 stars, 2nd has 1, 3rd has 3, 4 has 1. This code shows 7 stars for movie 1, same 7 stars for movie 2 and so on.